# JSON Multi Dimensional Array not shown on PHP

Tags: php, json

I make a normal API like this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$return = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","dummy");
$fetch = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM DATA "); 
while($re=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
    $return[] = $re;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

And its not showing anything in my laptop

Edit :

I read some article that PHP can't send more than 1000 request, and my api have more than 1000 data. After i add `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 20` it works normally.

Thanks for you guys that answer my question

Comment: Does your variable `$re` has any value? try to print it

Comment: maybe you have got error and it was suppressed because of configuration. Try `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your code

Comment: @pr1nc3 it have, i print_r it and it shows all the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $return = array();
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","dummy");
    $fetch = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `DATA`") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($re=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){
        $return[] = $re;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
```

Your code works. Try to escape DATA table name like above. Tested it locally and works fine for me the only issue i can see that may cause an issue is the table name.

Next time avoid to name your table with capital letters or with words that are mysql Keywords, or if you do, make sure to escape them using ` like i did in the above example. You will find additional info into this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Nice one. +1 from me. If you rly want to make it perfect, add some MySQLi error handler. But that's up to you.

Comment: Perfect :) As they say: _"Give a man a fish and he'll eat for a day. Teach him how to catch and he'll eat for lifetime"_

Comment: Still not working :( maybe i should reinstall my ammps

Comment: Your code is good, the error is somewhere else. Maybe in your Apache. Try to restart your local environment.